# Помогите аргументировать цитату

Tags: риторика

Цитата М. М. Сперанского: "Красноречие - это дар потрясать души, переливать в них свои страсти и сообщать им образ понятия".

Comment: Что вообще подразумевается под аргументацией цитаты? Мы тут больше по языку, как таковому, а это что-то уже из области литературы, даже журналистики какой-то...

Comment: Что поделать, если в экзамене по русскому языку есть такое задание - сочинение по проблеме? Это проверяет способность создавать тексты логически выдержанные, аргументированные. Вот к этим заданиям и готовятся.

Answer (score 1):

Я так думаю, Вам дан какой-то текст и аргументы надо искать там?

Если нет, если это просто эссе, можно рассуждать так:

"Красноречие - это дар потрясать души, переливать в них свои страсти и сообщать им образ понятия", - сказал М. Сперанский. Это действительно так, примеров тому немало в русской литературе.
Возьмём роман Тургенева "Рудин". Характер Рудина раскрывается в слове. Это гениальный оратор. “Рудин владел едва ли не высшей тайной - тайной красноречия. Он умел, ударяя по одним струнам сердец, заставлять смутно звенеть и дрожать все другие”. В своих философских речах о смысле жизни, о высоком назначении человека Рудин просто неотразим. Человек не может, не должен подчинять свою жизнь только практическим целям, заботам о существовании, - утверждает он. Без стремления отыскать “общие начала в частных явлениях” жизни, без веры в силу разума нет ни науки, ни просвещения, ни прогресса, а “если у человека нет крепкого начала, в которое он верит, нет почвы, на которой он стоит твердо, как может он дать себе отчет в потребностях, в значении, в будущности своего народа?”.
Просвещение, наука, смысл жизни - вот о чем говорит Рудин так увлеченно, вдохновенно и поэтично. Он рассказывает легенду о птице, залетевшей на огонь и опять скрывшейся в темноту. Казалось бы, человек, подобно этой птице, появляется из небытия и, прожив короткую жизнь, исчезает в безвестности. Да, “наша жизнь быстра и ничтожна; но все великое совершается через людей”.
Его высказывания вдохновляют и зовут к обновлению жизни, к необыкновенным, героическим свершениям. Силу воздействия Рудина на слушателей, убеждение словом ощущают все, в первую очередь Наталья Ласунская.

Талантом красноречия обладал и Петя Трофимов из "Вишнёвого сада" А. Чехова.
Когда он начинает говорить о светлом будущем родины, речь его звучит вдохновенно и образно. «Вся Россия наш сад, - восклицает он, обращаясь к Ане. - Земля велика и прекрасна, есть на ней много чудесных мест (пауза). Подумайте, Аня: ваш дед, прадед и все ваши предки были крепостники, владевшие живыми душами, и неужели с каждой ветки в саду, с каждого листка, с каждого ствола не глядят на вас человеческие существа, неужели вы не слышите голосов?» Трофимов видит, что за поэзией вишнёвого сада скрывается что-то уродливое и страшное. Слова его - приговор этому саду. Красноречие Пети заразило верой в светлое будущее Аню.
Таким образом, Сперанский прав, "красноречие - это дар потрясать души, переливать в них свои страсти и сообщать им образ понятия".

Comment: Людмила, написано, конечно, хорошо. Но разве может абитуриент за какой-то час (хотя время не важно) на экзамене так написать?

Comment: Я написала аргументы, как в ЕГЭ, так что это требование не к абитуриентам, а к школьникам, времени там достаточно, беда другая - редко кто читает, "Рудина" вряд ли кто вспомнит. Сейчас  хоть сочинение-допуск пишут, читать стали немного, а последние годы литературу забросили, идёт натаскивание на ЕГЭ по русскому.

Comment: Я не знаю, откуда такое задание - аргументировать цитату. Когда-то в ГИА было С1-лингвистическое сочинение, аргументы нужно было найти в тексте. А что это - не знаю.

Comment: Да, я тоже впервые вижу. Поэтому спросил.